# text with the same font size looks not the same size on different pages

Tags: css, font-size

on both pages,the font-size is 10pt,

but on one page the font size looks obviously bigger than on the other page,

what can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most certainly not 10pt then. Or, the page is zoomed. (View -> Zoom -> Reset, in firefox).

Note that CSS takes the most-specific selector (or the one with '!important'), so make sure you don't have something else overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

[The pt unit is only intended for print.](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/)

Are you sure you don't have one page defined as 'px' and the other 'pt'?

Answer (score 0):

You should install web developer toolbar - it will tell you the actually font size with the 'Display element information' option in the 'information' menu.